# Scanner picking up trash values?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm working on a program that is menu driven with numerical options for what the user would like to do. Upon entering `2`, the user is allowed to update their address by typing in a new address, like so:

```
if (edit == 2) {
    System.out.print("Please enter your new address: ");
    String address = in.nextLine();
    stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE PATIENTS " +
        "SET ADDRESS = '" + address + "' " +
        "WHERE LOGIN = '" + username + "'");
}
```

The issue I am having is as soon as the user enters option `2`, they are never able to attempt to input their address as the program believes that a null value was entered and then tries to execute the update statement on the database, which fails because the address cannot be `NULL`.

Is there a reason that a trash value is being picked up that I am missing? It seems to work okay for the other options where the user is attempting to edit their name, age, etc. using `in.next()` and `in.nextInt()`. For whatever reason, the `in.nextLine()` is defaulting to `NULL` before the user has a chance to input anything.

I have tried putting a `String trash = in.next();` line before reading `in.nextLine()`. This stops the program from crashing, but it cuts off the numerical part of the address.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem you're having, but please read about SQL injection, because your code as it stands has a classic security problem: http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html

Comment: Use `PreparedStatement` or meet [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Thank you both for the friendly reminder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using `in.nextInt()` to retrieve `edit`.  When you do that there will still be a newline (`\n`) on the input stream, so your call to `in.nextLine()` is retrieving that newline.  The other methods will ignore whitespace so the newline is consumed by them and they work as you expect.

If you call `in.nextLine()` twice the second call will return the line you are looking for.  Alternatively, you may want to call `in.nextLine()` when you retrieve the `edit` value and parse the integer from there.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick. What is the standard practice? Is it always best to call `in.nextLine()` and parse it as an integer for number-driven menus?

Comment: It really depends on what you are doing.  If all of your menus are numbers then it's fine to not call `in.nextLine()`.  Anytime you are mixing the two you need to consider when you are leaving a newline on the input and make sure you consume it.  When you mix the two it's really a design decision.  It may be easier just to call `in.nextInt()` and then `in.nextLine()` to get rid of everything after the number.  That also helps in case the user enters multiple numbers on the same line because it will ignore everything after the first number instead of trying to use it for future values.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this

```
in.skip("\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085]");
```

just above the

```
in.nextLine();
```

that should keep you from skipping the input and will also be nice if you are using any type of loops as sometimes an additional in.nextLine() will cause headaches.